# how to get full category path including parent and subcategories

Tags: categories, slug

How do I get the full category path including the subcategories?

I am using

```
if ( is_archive() ) {
    $term = get_queried_object();
    $page_path = $term->slug;
}
```

`https://mandoemedia.com/blog/topic/aaa-1ndustries/beauty/` this returns `beauty` only, **not** `aaa-1ndustries/beauty`.

How do I grab the parent category and subcategory, i.e. `aaa-1ndustries/beauty`?

The previous developer added some code to prefix post categories with `/blog/topic/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I grab the parent category and subcategory, i.e. `aaa-1ndustries/beauty`?

Well if you meant the **current** category URL, where it looks like `https://example.com/blog/topic/aaa-1ndustries/beauty/`, and you just wanted to get the above category path from that URL, then try this:

```php
$request   = $GLOBALS['wp']->request;
$page_path = trim( preg_replace( '#^blog/topic/#', '', $request ), '/' );
```

And if you want to do the same for a specific category URL/**permalink**, you can use [`get_category_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_link/) (or [`get_term_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/) for custom taxonomies) and [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```php
$cat_id    = 123; // change the value to the correct category ID
$request   = parse_url( get_category_link( $cat_id ), PHP_URL_PATH );
$page_path = trim( preg_replace( '#^/blog/topic/#', '', $request ), '/' );
```

But if you actually wanted to get the **actual *hierarchical path*** of the category, then use [`get_category_parents()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_parents/) (or [`get_term_parents_list()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_parents_list/) for custom taxonomies). E.g.

```php
// Use this for the core `category` taxonomy:
$cat_id   = get_queried_object_id(); // or just set a specific category ID
$cat_path = get_category_parents( $cat_id, false, '/', true );

// OR use this for custom taxonomies:
$term     = get_queried_object(); // or just set a specific term object
$cat_path = get_term_parents_list( $term->term_id, $term->taxonomy, array(
    'separator' => '/',
    'link'      => false,
    'format'    => 'slug',
) );

echo trim( $cat_path, '/' ); // the trim() removes the trailing/last slash
```

Comment: You are my coding hero, again Sally

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get full category path then you can use `get_term_link()`.
So your code shoud change as

```
if ( is_archive() ) {
    $term = get_queried_object();
    $full_path = get_term_link($term);
}
```